# Strange error while redirecting in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I have simple code to redirect user to a other page on button click. Below is my code

```
protected void BtnBackList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Redirect("product_list.aspx?source=fromdetail");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex);
    }
}
```

Code is very simple. It was working fine. But suddenly it started a strange issue. On click instead of redirection , page go on loading for 10 to 15 min and then it shows "**The Connection was reset**" error.

Tried to capture details in **Fiddler** and it show

> '[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: something in product_list.aspx is broken.

Comment: If you can provide the details of the Page load method of your product_list.aspx then it would be helpful to understand. Basically want to know on the page load what's happening and causing this problem.

Comment: Response.Redirect("/product_list.aspx?source=fromdetail"); Please use this.

Comment: here you have a link you can follow
http://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-readresponse()-failed-the-server-did-not-return-a-response-for-this-request-server-returned-0-bytes

Comment: I don't think any issue is there in product_list.aspx page, as same page getting called from another 5-6 place and working fine. I mean same code is there in another 5-6 pages also and from there redirection is fine.

Comment: I googled: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_

Comment: try Response.Redirect("product_list.aspx?source=fromdetail", false);

Comment: Does the BtnBackList_Click handler get executed?  Is the relative path to product_list.aspx correct?  Does Fiddler show the request to product_list.apx before timing out. or does it time out on the POST when you click on BtnBackList?

Comment: @caras Already modified, but no result. Response.Redirect("product_list.aspx?source=fromdetail", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: maybe the problem is on the other page?  (product_list.aspx) did you check other page?

Comment: @caras There is not any issue in product_list.aspx page. It is working fine from all other pages.

Comment: @Joe, yes the handler get executed and path is correct. Request does not get redirected to product_list.aspx page. I got HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure response.